# Why are simple models of coupled pendulums incapable of describing irreversible energy dissipation?

Tags: reversibility, dissipation, models, open-quantum-systems

Consider two pendulums $A$ and $B$ coupled by a spring and also regard $A+B$ to be a completely isolated system. Let us start the system in an initial configuration where only one of the pendulums (say, $A$) is displaced keeping the other (i.e. $B$) at rest. As time passes, all the energy of $A$ is transferred to $B$ that was initially at rest. At one point $A$ comes to rest, momentarily and $B$ carries all the energy. Eventually, the situation reverses and the cycle continues back and forth.

In this very simple example, if we regard one of the pendulums (say, $A$) to be our system of interest and $B$ acting as its environment, we see that there is no permanent dissipation of energy of $A$. Even if we track the motion of $A$ only, its energy is not irreversibly lost to $B$ (its environment). It regains all of its energy periodically without any damping.

> *So this simple example above illustrates that just diving a compound system into two parts and keeping track of the degrees of freedom of one part *only* will not necessarily lead to dissipation.*

The example above could be extended to a system of $n$ coupled oscillators. Here too, starting with a similar initial configuration, if we regard one of the oscillators to be the system, and all the other acting as its environment, the energy of A is *not*  irreversibly lost to the remaining $(n-1)$ oscillators.

**Question** Why do these models described above fail to capture the phenomenon of dissipation? What are the feature of the environment of an actual pendulum (i.e. a real pendulum immersed in the atmosphere) and its coupling that causes its energy to be irreversibly lost to the environment (the atmosphere)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a model with a finite-dimensional Hilbert space, however large, energy cannot be *irreversibly* lost from one part of the system. However, if the Hilbert space has $10^{10000000000}$ dimensions, then the local energy-loss can be close enough to irreversible for all practical purposes.

The atmosphere can (and does) emit electromagnetic radiation. Some of that electromagnetic radiation escapes into space. The electromagnetic field can be viewed as a large number of oscillators, a few for each point in space.  That's uncountably many oscillators if we model space as a continuum, but even if we model space as discrete, space is pretty big, so that's still a *lot* of oscillators. Maybe not $10^{10000000000}$ of them, but easily enough to make the recurrence time longer than anything we could ever hope to observe.

That's a practical answer. Regarding questions of principle, [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.3796) has some thought-provoking things to say about recurrence times in a cosmological setting.

Comment: _"In a model with a finite-dimensional Hilbert space, however large, energy cannot be irreversibly lost from one part of the system."_ Is this some theorem in the theory of open quantum systems? If I understand you correctly, then for a gigantic dimensional Hilbert space, like the one you mention, the physical reason for practically irreversible local energy loss is that the time for the local degrees of freedom to come back to its initial configuration is cosmologically large. Does that mean, in my simple classical model, making $n\to \infty$ will lead to dissipation? @ChiralAnomaly

Comment: @SRS  I'll have to think for a while to find/prove that assertion as a theorem, but I *should* be able to (I'm scolding myself for not having it on the top of my head), so I will try to find/prove a theorem.

Comment: @SRS And yes, in your classical coupled-pendulums model, making $n\to\infty$ should generally lead to dissipation. There can be exceptions, where the model or the initial state is contrived to prevent dissipation, but I'm pretty sure that dissipation will be the typical behavior. Intuitively, this follows from conservation of energy: there are infinitely many places for the energy to go, and if nothing stops it from going there, then it will, which leaves less energy in the original location, and so on forever.

Comment: @SRS Regarding the theorem: It's called the **Poincaré recurrence theorem**, and Wikipedia has a decent introduction to it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_recurrence_theorem. Near the bottom of the page is a section called "quantum mnechanical version," which outlines a proof.